# Google Play Services - Push notification

Tags: android, google-play-services

Currently, on my app that uses Google Play Services, when a user invites another to play (real time multiplayer), Play Games alerts the receiving user that there is a game waiting. But it does not send a notification, so the receiving user would have to know he is receiving an invitation (i.e. it doesn't show on the status bar of the phone like all the other notifications, but shows when you pull down the status bar).
Is there a way of alerting the user?

Comment: options: 1. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html 2. do it your self.. write a remote service that check every x-time for  new messages ..

Comment: GCM seems like a good option, thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem.